# How to execute a function involving agent within a process block in AnyLogic

Tags: anylogic

I'm using a code in the On Enter field of a Delay block and I've noticed the code is executed only once when the agent enter the block (as expected). However, as this code has a condition that agents should meet before proceeding to the next block, whenever the condition is not met (on Enter), agent get stuck in the block. I need this code to be executed daily rather than just once and, of course, only for the agent in that block, rather than to the entire population.

Any guesses?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another option: Use a Dynamic Event `MyDE` in your Agent.

On entering the Delay block, you trigger the DE using `create_MyDE(0, SECOND);`.

In the DE, you check your condition:

```
if (myConditionIsMet) {
    main.delayBlock.remove(this); // free this agent from the delay block
} else {
    create_MyDE(24, HOUR); // check again in 24 hrs
}
```

The agent will stay in the Delay block until the condition is true, which is checked every 24 hrs (but not thereafter)

Comment: Thank you for your response Ben . I've tried both alternative and they resulted in weird behaviour although the syntax are correct. I don't know why my statechart is not working and the alternative with a dynamic event used all my computer RAM and didn't run (I've put 16Gb).

Comment: Feel free to open a new specific question with more details ;) Probably some logic detail you are missing

Comment: Thank you Ben! I sorted this issue with a function and an event directly in Main that used a for loop looking into the agents waiting in the block and checking for the condition I need on a hourly basis.

Answer (score 0):

Many different options, actually. Here is one:

Create a state chart within the agent itself. On entering the Delay block, you trigger the state chart to enter a new state that has a daily internal transition. This then checks if the agent can leave the delay block. If so, you trigger that and exit the state.